# Encryption event is not working perfectly in Codeignator

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I am not expert in the Codeignator. I watch videos on youtube and surfing on the google and found some good tutorials to understand the Codeignator.
I am getting the issue on archive record.

My archive event is sometimes working sometimes not working. I mean, I am clicking more than 2 times then working and some time not working.

```
Not even archive, I am getting the issue on pending, view etc
```

Explain in the details from start to end each step.

**Controller**

```
public function employee_list(){
          $get_emp_data['get_emp_records'] = $this->Employee_model->get_emp_records(); //getting all the employee records
          $this->load->view('employee_list',$get_emp_data);//sending all the employee details in the employee list  page
   }
```

**Employee list view page**

```
    <?php if (!empty($get_emp_records)) {?>
    <table class="table " >  
            <thead>
             <tr>  
              <th>Employee Name</th> 
               <th>Designation</th>  
               <th>Role</th>  
               <th>Status</th>  
               <th>Action</th>               
             </tr> 
              </thead>
             <?php  
             foreach ($get_emp_records as $row)  
             { $encryption_id=$this->encryption->encrypt($row->id);//encrpt the id ?>

                <tbody>
                <tr>   
                <td><?php echo $row->firstname;  echo $row->lastname;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->designation;?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $row->access_role;?></td>
                <?php if ($row->is_approved == 1): ?>
                <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Approved</a></td>
                <?php else: ?>
                <td><a  href="<?php echo site_url('Employee_control/approved_user?key='.$encryption_id)?>">Pending</a></td>
<?php endif; ?>

              <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('Employee_control/get_employee_edit?key='.$encryption_id)?>">View</a> 
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('Employee_control/employee_archive?key='.$encryption_id)?>">Archive</a>
              </td>    
                </tr>   
              </tbody> 
             <?php }       
             ?>              
       </table>  
    <?php }else{echo "No record found";}?>
```

Getting output

[image]

Till now I don't have any issue without encrypting the id it's working perfectly.

Now what I did I set id encryption and my steps are

```
1) autoload.php($autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation','encryption');) // I added
2) config.php($config['encryption_key'] = 'hex2bin(9753b368fe0da4efec19ec55ff0b8407)';)// added encription key. I created using $key = bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(16));
3)I added in the view(employee list)$encryption_id=$this->encryption->encrypt($row->id);//encrpt the id
```

Now when admin click on the archive then it will redirect on the controller which I added below

**Controller**

```
public function employee_archive(){
          $archive_key_id=$this->encryption->decrypt($this->input->get('key'));//getting the value rom URl and decryting it.
          $archive_emp['archive_emp'] = $this->Employee_model->employee_archive($archive_key_id); //updating the is_archve field and approved date
          redirect("Employee_control/employee_list");
  }
```

**Model**

```
public function employee_archive($archive_key_id){
$data = array(
               'is_archive' => 1,
               'archived_date' => $this->current_date,
               'archive_by' => $this->session->userdata['login_session']['id']

            );

$this->db->where('id', $archive_key_id);
$this->db->update('tbl_employee', $data); 
}
```

Sometime archive event is working sometimes not working. I think there is some issue with my encryption because without encryption it's working perfectly.

also, check whenever I refresh the page it's changing the encryption id.

Hope you guys understand my issue.
Would you help me out in this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally, I found my answer.

Please suggest me for best answer.

I tried `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()`

**Employee list view page**

I added

```
$encryption_id=base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($row->id));//encrpt the id
```

and decode

```
   $approved_key_id=$this->encryption->decrypt(base64_decode($this->input->get('key')));//getting the value from URl
```

and It's working perfectly for me.

Comment: Please anyone know the best answer then please share instated of the downvote. That will be a great help for me